# Laravel Foreach Repeating in View

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So, I have a form that has multiple text inputs. When the user posts info using these inputs it's put into my model with the user's ID, a "type ID", and the input from the user. So I'll end up with something like this in the database.

```
ID    User_ID    Type_ID    Type_Details
1        1          1           yada
2        1          1           foo
3        1          1           bar
```

In my view I do this.

```
@foreach ($user->UserType as $type)
```

What happens is that in the view I then get the output 3 times, since it sees "type_id" for user #1. For reference, this table shown is a pivot table joining the user model and the type model. I simply added another column to retrieve the type_details information.

Ultimately, since there is only one Type_id (1), I want to only show that type once with the "yada", "foo", "bar". Not 3 times.

Thanks!

Comment: How you exactly want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a foreach, you can group the types using `Collections`:

```
$types = $user->UserType->implode('Type_Details', ', ')->toArray();
```

Then you can display in your view as:

```
{{ $types }}
```

Comment: Is it best practice to use collections and push to the view instead of using Eloquent? Does it really matter?

Comment: Eloquent also uses collections so it doesn't make a difference.